# dynamic spacing with printf in Java

Tags: java, dynamic, printf

I have the following code, which works but the dynamic spacing seems pretty cluegy.  Is there a more direct approach?

```
public class BubbleSort{
    static int[] unsorted = new int[10];
    public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException{
          clearScreen();        
          
          for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
              unsorted[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
          }
          
          printArray();
          Thread.sleep(3000);
          int x = 0;
          String space=" ";
          
          
          for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.length - 1; i++){
              for(int j = 0; j < unsorted.length - 1 - i; j++){
                  
                  if(unsorted[j] > unsorted[j+1]){
                      int temp = unsorted[j];
                      unsorted[j] = unsorted[j+1];
                      unsorted[j+1] = temp;                                            
                  }
                  if(x == 0) System.out.printf("\n" + "%2d  %2d\n",j,(j+1));
                  else System.out.printf("\n%" +x + "s%2d  %2d\n",space,j,(j+1));
                  x+=4;
                  if(x > 34)x = 0;
                  printArray();
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                  System.out.println();
              }              
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of a question you asked already: [create dynamic spacing with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74646224/12567365).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the "spacer" dynamically, instead of printing a fixed-length spacer with offset. So instead of

```java
if(x == 0) System.out.printf("\n" + "%2d  %2d\n",j,(j+1));
else System.out.printf("\n%" +x + "s%2d  %2d\n",space,j,(j+1));
```

do this:

```java
System.out.printf("%n%s%2d  %2d%n", space.repeat(x), j, (j + 1));
```